# How to make the Amazon Fire TV Web App compatible with Ad Servers?

Tags: web-applications, webview, html5-video, amazon-fire-tv, advertisement-server

I'd like to rebuild my Amazon Fire TV Web App so that it will be compatible with Ad Servers.  My App is built with Amazon's "WASK" SDK, it's not the typical droid build.

I found a few companies that do Ad Insertions of videos ads via VAST, VPAID and PODs, but their SDK's and/or "TAGs" only work on Android based Fire TV apps.

I've been told that the online video player (I think it's webview) may be presenting some of the development difficulties.

Any ideas or solutions are welcome...I just want to find a way to monetize my app with video ads running as Pre-roll/Midroll etc etc.

Thank you.